# Shouldn't there be a badge for visiting the site everyday for a year?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I have visited this website for 333 consecutive days.

Got a gold badge for 100 days. Should not there be a badge or a token of recognition for visiting the website continuously for a year?

Comment: seems like a request for platinum badge

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At some point, it's just excessive to continue pushing people to log in Every. Single. Day. A hundred days is an accomplishment, yes, but it's 'only' a little more than three months.

Badges drive behavior, and I believe that an unbroken year-long streak isn't something we should try to push. It's not healthy.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if we have a badge it does not mean we are pushing, but if someone get's it, it is great.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Right, having it doesn't mean you are puching *right now*, but if anything, activity on SO has proven that people will go through great effort to collect badges. Imagine: "log in each day for a year" or "log in at least once per 6 hours for 100 days."

Comment: By that criteria, I am practically dead (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309). But I agree: there is a difference between a daily visit for training, and a meaningless year-long pursuit of a badge.